# slicing tuple out of index in a form of x[0:4:-1]

Tags: python, tuples

`x = (1, 2, 3, 4)`

Here, `x[0:4:-1]` gives an empty `tuple` `()`. Why is this happening? 
I thought it would just give a reversed tuple `(4,3,2,1)`...

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for all of the values starting at 0, ending before 4, counting by -1 at a time. That's no values.

What you want to do is start at 3, end before -1, counting by -1 at a time. Except… you can't put `-1` in there, because that means "1 from the end". So, you have to write "start at 3, end when you've exhausted the whole sequence, counting by -1 at a time", like this:

```
x[3::-1]
```

Or, more simply:

```
x[::-1]
```

---

It may help your understanding to turn the slice into an explicit loop. It looks something like this:

```
def slicify(sequence, start, end, step):
    if start < 0: start += len(sequence)
    if end < 0: end += len(sequence)
    result = []
    while (start < end if step > 0 else start > end):
        result.append(sequence[start])
        start += step
    return result
```

But this is only roughly correct. The exact definition is in the documentation under [Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), under note 5:

> The slice of `s` from `i` to `j` with step `k` is defined as the sequence of items with index `x = i + n*k` such that `0 <= n < (j-i)/k`. In other words, the indices are `i`, `i+k`, `i+2*k`, `i+3*k` and so on, stopping when `j` is reached (but never including `j`). If `i` or `j` is greater than `len(s)`, use `len(s)`. If `i` or `j` are omitted or `None`, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of `k`). Note, `k` cannot be zero. If `k` is `None`, it is treated like `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to either omit the start and end, or *reverse* the start and end:

```
x[::-1]    # (4, 3, 2, 1)
x[3:0:-1]  # (4, 3, 2)
x[3::-1]   # (4, 3, 2, 1)
x[3:-5:-1] # (4, 3, 2, 1)
```

The end point is not included, so slicing with `[3:0:-1]` only returns *three* elements. The last example uses a negative value to be subtracted from the length of the tuple to end up with endpoint `-1`.

Using a negative stride means Python wants to count backwards, and starting at 0 you'll never get to 4.

Note that the Python slice syntax applies to more than just tuples; strings and lists support the exact same syntax.